# Is there a way to return an array of values using filter function based on two "include" conditions in filter function in Excel / Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a matrix of shops and raw materials as shown below

Item Name   Shop A  Shop B  Shop C  Shop C  Shop D  Shop E
AISI 4340   Yes Yes     Yes     Yes
17-4PH      Yes Yes
AISI 4140
SS 304          Yes
SS 301  Yes         Yes Yes
AISI 1010   Yes     Yes     Yes
AISI 1020   Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes
AA 7075 T6  Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes
AA 7075 T351            Yes
AA 6061 T6  Yes Yes Yes     Yes Yes

"Yes" means raw material is available at that shop.
Now I am struggling with filter function to return an array of companies which have a given material. given material is mentioned in a separate cell and is one of the item names in the above matrix.

Google sheet link for [my document here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AJ9ur4o4FverKQNb1Z0y1Mowb2STGPPx17S1vY7P81g/edit#gid=306542252)

I am trying to use formula

> =transpose(FILTER(C3:H3;(C4:H13="Yes")*B4:B13=J3))
> in cell J5 but it is giving me an error

I tried different approaches to get to the desired result without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=tocol(filter(C3:H3; filter(C4:H13;B4:B13=J3)="Yes"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The solution has perfectly worked.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(TOCOL(IF(B4:B13&C4:H13=J3&"Yes",C3:H3,),1))
```

[image]